# Does Bangladesh and India's economy face similar economic obstacles?

Tags: macroeconomics

I had a question : Does Bangladesh and India's economy face similar economic obstacles (Poverty, education, unemployment etc) or are they different in their own terms ? I'd be extremely grateful if anyone could answer this question as I really need it for my EPQ. Many thanks.

Comment: http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is to look at the World Development Indicators (WDI) of the World Bank. You may compare [Bangladesh](http://data.worldbank.org/country/bangladesh) and [India](http://data.worldbank.org/country/india)'s economy over hundred indicators.

For instance, you will find that the percentage of the population living below the national poverty lines was around 31.5% in Bangladesh (in 2010) versus 21.9% in India (in 2011). The [2014 annual report](http://data.worldbank.org/sites/default/files/wdi-2014-book.pdf) documents that the unemployment rate was quite low in both countries between 2008 and 2012, around 4-5%.